# Update replace values from one sheet to another google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to update rows if they are found in sheet1 with data from sheet2 based on a key column.  Also if the key is not found then add a new row.  I have figured out iterating over the range from sheet2, but not how to lookup the value in sheet1.  Any suggestions welcome.   (I upddated the post here.)

```
function getJulaUpdates2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Franco-Jula"); 
  var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var values1 = range1.getValues()

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Jula-Alternatives");
  var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var values2 = range2.getValues()

  // Iterate through sheet2
  // Start at 1 to avoid header row
  for (var i = 1; i < values2.length; i++) {

     // Now loop through Values1 sheet
    for (var x = 1; x < values1.length; x++) {
      logthis = values2[i][0] + "," + values1[x][1];

      if (values1[x][1] == values2[i][0]) {
          values1[x][2] = values2[i][2]
          values1[x][12] = values2[i][12]           
          values1[x][13] = values2[i][13]

      Logger.log(logthis);
      }

    }
  }
range1.setValues(values1)
}
```

Comment: Why not iterate values from sheet1 same way as sheet2?

Comment: ok I did get that far today.   The only problem now is that i am updateing sheet1 from sheet2 but not adding rows that don't exist.  My brain is thinking lookup something that's equal to x and if it isn't found then add it.

Comment: You're going to need to be much more specific and detailed. You claim a key column exists - on which sheet? `sheet1`? `sheet2`? Both? Is it the same column on both?

Comment: ok yes I have a key column and this is working to update the sheet.          if (values1[x][1] == values2[i][0]) {
          values1[x][2] = values2[i][2].   As noted I also need to add rows that don't exist.

Comment: I updated my question with code that is updating sheet but not adding new rows.

Comment: To add a new row to your output variable (`values1`), you need to `push` the entire row you want to write. I recommend adding it to a new array (one you aren't iterating over), and then when you are done iterating, combine your existing output with the new arrays. To know if you need to add, you should set a flag when you find the key in your inner loop. Lastly, you must get a new `Range` reference (since your output's size no longer matches the size of `range1`). Review the `getRange(row, col, numRows, numCols)` Apps Script documentation, and Javascript Array methods `push`, `concat`.